# Why passing address of pointer to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I come across the functions like strtok_s where you will need to pass a pointer to pointer argument.

```
strtok_r(char *restrict str, const char *restrict sep, char **restrict lasts);
```

The way to use it is:

```
char *foo;
char *str = ...;
char *delimiter = ...;
strtok_r(str, delimiter, &foo);
```

Wondering why pass the address of pointer foo into the function?

Comment: The same reason you pass the address of an `int` or of a `struct`: because c does pass-by-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so that `strtok` can resume where it left off. This version of `strtok` is thread safe (since it uses a pointer you supply and not the internal pointer of the other version).

It saves the address of the last token read in a `char *` so you need to pass a pointer to that pointer so it can change the value and return it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Because `strtok` is not reentrant while `strok_r` is. This means that you can't safely call it from multiple threads. To fix this, it is necessary for the function to store its status somewhere and this can be done by passing a pointer to a pointer so that strok_r is able to modify value of the pointer passed (which is another pointer) as argument.

Answer (score 0):

the function `strtok_r(str, delimiter, &foo)` puts its output into `foo` and needs a pointer to it in order to no just replace the (copied) input object.